# in polymer js do we have any event for element fully templatized or element is fully loaded. To avoid async function

Tags: polymer-1.0, polymer-2.x

To avoid Polymer.async in attached. how do I come to know that element is fully templatized or fully loaded.
How do I know all the data binding and data are stamped.

Answer (score 0):

Module for scheduling flushable pre-render and post-render tasks.

```
ready() {
    super.ready();
    Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender(this, () => {
       //
    }  

}
```

for more [details](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/namespaces/Polymer.RenderStatus)

- Requires import: lib/utils/render-status.html

Comment: I tried this but it seems like it is calling after all the instance of the same component loaded. let's say I have 5 component on page.. If I add afterNextRender in ready. That call will be invoked after all the 5 component loaded. I want to that call would be there after each component loaded.

Comment: Please add your code. And where you try to run your script. And when you want to run? What kind error you have?